# When did 'want' stop meaning "in need of"

Tags: historical-change

When did the word 'want' stop meaning "in need of" or 'lacking' and begin to refer to desire? (Evidence old phrases with the original meaning like: "want for nothing" or "waste not, want not".)

Comment: I am now somewhat embarrassed to say that I still use "want" in that context.

Comment: I haven't found Google ngrams very reliable in that often recent books appear with older timestamps but in any event the phrase "wants vs needs" definitely appears to have become more common since the 1960s. http://i.stack.imgur.com/405bg.jpg

Answer (score 21):

Not yet.

> **want**
>
> 1. have a desire to possess or do (something); wish for.
>      "I want an apple"
>      synonyms:   desire, wish for, hope for, aspire to, fancy, care for, like; More
> 2. (archaic)
>      lack or be short of something desirable or essential.
>      "you shall want for nothing while you are with me"
>      noun
> 3. (archaic)
>      a lack or deficiency of something.
>      "Victorian houses which are in want of repair"
>      synonyms:   lack, absence, nonexistence, unavailability; More
> 4. a desire for something.
>      "the expression of our wants and desires"
>      synonyms:   wish, desire, demand, longing, yearning, fancy, craving, hankering;
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=want)

> **archaic**
>
> 1. very old or old-fashioned.
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=archaic)

Old doesn't mean dead.  Thus, I find the assumption that this meaning has ceased, wanting.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that lack and desire are two sides of the same coin so the meaning hasn't changed all that much.  How do you lack something you have no desire for?  Bit of Buddhist philosophy in this word.

Comment: +1 for "Old doesn't mean dead." Something youngsters can usefully bear in mind...

Comment: I often *need* to eat, but have no *desire* to. I would happily go without food for the rest of my life (it would be rather short, I guess). So, I have a need for something that I do not desire, on a daily basis. The *lack* comes in when I finally force myself to make dinner and realize that I have to also walk to the grocery store because "the cupboard is bare". At least the walk is pleasant... But that is probably a need also. A huge distinction in common life is Want / Need / Addiction. I say, if you Want (desire) it, then effectively it is a need, because eventually it must be satisfied.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: It seems plausible that's how the modern meaning came about, in fact. People said "I want a place to stay for the night" meaning "I don't have one", but if they had no need or desire for one then they wouldn't bother mentioning it, and so the meaning shades over to "I want a place to stay for the night and I will that I get one". Maybe.

Comment: As for the Buddhist philosophy side of things, note that perspectives vary and so the language does distinguish whether something is desirable and whether you actually desire it. "Boy, you want manners", "No I don't, you old fool, I'm perfectly happy without them" ;-)

Comment: @CandiedOrange - A very good point. T don't understand the question - 'want' has not changed its meaning. You desire what you lack, you lack what you desire.

Comment: @Zane: I think that the usage has gotten rather confused. I can lack lots of things but not desire them. There is no substantial furniture in my apartment for example, and my bed is an air mattress on the floor, and that is just fine with me. (To others it looks like a lack.) When I am looking at my fiancee, she is right there, and I desire her. So it is easily possible that want could mean an unfulfilled *need*, which is no part of either lack or desire (hunger when you have food available). That is why we have all three words. If we didn't *need* them for clarity, we would not *desire* them.

Comment: I'm surprised that Google says that "want" meaning "lack or deficieny" is archaic and then uses the definitely current phrase "in want of repair" as an example. I agree that this usage is now quite rare in general use, I can't imagine saying "I am in want of more cloud storage space" for example, but there are a few set phrases which preserve it such as "in want of repair" and "in want of sustenance" which are still used, particularly in formal contexts.

Answer (score 8):

There is a film short written and directed by Keir Black called *[I **Want** for Nothing](https://kinofilm.org.uk/made-up-north-sat-27th-feb/)* made in 2008 (but not released yet).

Listen to the song "[I **Want** for Nothing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=he1CNlC9FWo)," a 2009 effort of the band Wye Oak.

From the 2000 book *[Texas Anthem](https://books.google.com/books?id=yThDCU2ttzgC&pg=PT21&dq=%22want%20for%20nothing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgr8ft_NLJAhXHgj4KHd8kA6EQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22want%20for%20nothing%22&f=false)* by Kerry Newcomb:

> I'll be a good husband to you, Rose.  And we'll have a wonderful life.
> You'll be my queen, I promise, and you'll **want** for nothing.

The historical change may be acoming, but it's not here yet.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you.  It's also better because that's how it's printed in the book.  The first two sentences I had to type; the last two I got to copy and paste.  That explains the transcription error but not the proofreading goof.

Comment: OK, you win: once in a while someone uses the 'archaic' meaning of Want. But 99.9% of the time, people **mean** desire. This is what I am talking about. Are you any relation to Deadmou5?

Comment: Not sure I agree that just because it is used in that form in some well-known phrases doesn't mean it's not archaic (not that I disagree with the point in this case, just with the argument itself). "the lady doth protest too much" is still used, but I certainly wouldn't consider "doth" to be current.

Comment: @nocomprende I win?  Great!  What do I get?  Assuming that *want for* ("I want for nothing"), *for want* ("for want of a nail"), and *wanting* ("I find your explanation wanting") are the only uses for what you've called the archaic sense, the Ngram viewer says 95%.  (And assuming I can do arithmetic, for which there is some contrary evidence).

Comment: @Voo *Want* in the sense of lack is certainly much less used than *want* in the sense of desire, but it's not quite restricted to set phrases.  Yet.  Another piece of missing information is whether the former is on a glide path to extinction or whether it's just always been the minority use.  The Ngram viewer, an imperfect tool, suggests a decline.

Comment: @nocomprende Assuming you mean deadmau5, the Canadian musician Joel Thomas Zimmerman, the answer is no.  I've been using the nym deadrat before such a thing was called a nym and before Zimmerman was born.

Comment: You can get anything you want, at Alice's Restaurant. I don't know what a nym is, I just liked some of his music. I also don't know what ngram viewer is, I just use the language with the people around me, and 95% of the people don't even understand the lesser used meaning.

Comment: 'Cept Alice.  I'm not as old as Arlo.  "Nym" is short for *psedonym"; it's the name you use online, no comprende.  The Ngram viewer is https://books.google.com/ngrams.  It finds words and phrases in published books and graphs their frequency of occurrence.